# Error code in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for some help with my code...

```
# save text file to string
data = File.read("workdata.txt")

# split string into blocks of text relevant to each journey
journeys = data.split(/\n\s\n/)

# store the amount of journeys as a variable called journeys_size
journeys_size = journeys.length

# split each journey into lines and save to an array called "journey_lines"
@journey_lines = journeys.map { |i| i.split(/\n/) }

# cretae an array called "all_journey_objects" to hold all journeys
all_journey_objects = []   

# step through the journey arrays 
@journey_lines.each do |line|

next if line[0].include?("position") # skip the journey block of text if it contains position

destinations = []
destination1 = line[12].upcase 
destination2 = line[13].scan(/[a-z]+/i).join(" ").upcase
#   destination3 = line[14].scan(/[a-z]+/i).join(" ").upcase   # <---- When i uncomment this line **
#   destination4 = line[15].scan(/[a-z]+/i).join(" ").upcase
#   destination5 = line[16].scan(/[a-z]+/i).join(" ").upcase

puts destination1
puts destination2
#   puts destination3   #  <---- When i uncomment this line **
#   puts destination5
#   puts destination4

#   journey = Journey.new(line[0] , line[1] , line[6] , destinations, etas, windows)
#   all_journey_objects << journey
end
```

The problem I am having is the following error when executed:

```
watcher.rb:47: in 'block in <main>': undefined method'scan' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I think the reason is because the "workdata.txt" file that I am working with, contains some journeys which only have two destinations. So, as soon as i uncomment the lines to create a third destination variable it throws an error. Maybe because it is trying to run a method against an object that doesn't exist?

I am stuck with finding a way around this. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: The error occurred in file `watcher.rb` on line 47. The code above doesn't have a 47th line …

Comment: Sorry, i left out a section at the start to make my post shorter. I can see how that might be confusing. The line 47 relates to the line which I uncomment out, with the <-- arrow in the above code. I can repost with the whole code if that is easier? Thanks for the response

Comment: The method name seems to be missing from the error message: `undefined method''` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what this code is supposed to do so we can suggest an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is line 47:

```
destination3 = line[14].scan(/[a-z]+/i).join(" ").upcase
```

`` undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass `` indicates that you are sending `scan` to `nil`. In other words, `line[14]` is `nil`.

You could simply add an `if` statement:

```
if line[14]
  destination3 = line[14].scan(/[a-z]+/i).join(" ").upcase
end
```

Or an inline `if`:

```
destination3 = line[14].scan(/[a-z]+/i).join(" ").upcase if line[14]
```